# Sql Result two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Full name status
ricardo 1 2
ricardo 2 4
```

How do I make a select to return like this:

```
name     totalstatus1 totalstatus2 total
ricardo   2            4             6
```

Comment: This ig going to sound nit-picky - but which 2 is it using? The value from the first row or from the second row?
Can you post a sample there there are no repeated values so we can be sure to see them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not include the name of the column with the `2` and `4` but you could use something similar to this:

```
select name,
  sum(case when status = 1 then value end) totalStatus1,
  sum(case when status = 2 then value end) totalStatus2,
  sum(value) Total
from yourtable
group by name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b89d/1)